# How to force MapKit to use Google Mobile Maps (GMM) beyond iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, mapkit

The [Map Kit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008210) says:

> In iOS5.1 and earlier,the Map Kit framework uses the Google Mobile Maps (GMM) service to provide map data.

If I use the `MapKit` framework for displaying maps, it is using google maps for iOS 5.1 and earlier, for iOS 6 it uses apples new maps. Can I force `MapKit` to still use goggle mobile maps instead?

Related Links:
[What's new in iOS6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011812-SW1), [Location Awarness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497)

Comment: load google.maps url in a UIWebview

Comment: @AnilKothari but I need annotations and `MKReverseGeocoder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible.

With iOS 6 and above, you cannot access Google Maps natively. If you wish to use MapKit on iOS 6, you're stuck with Apple Maps. End of. This shouldn't be too much of a problem; MapKit should work seamlessly with either Google Maps on iOS 5 and Apple Maps on iOS 6, and you use the same API and code in either version.

You can still access Google Maps via URL (http://maps.google.com/...), and send the user to it via Safari, or maybe using a `UIWebView`, but the functionality you have will be fairly restricted (only what's possible to pass in the URL as parameters). You'll have a lot of work cut out for yourself if you want to support Google Maps in iOS 6.